# How to run Javafx stage/scene in Swing Application?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, fxmlloader, jfxpanel

I have a swing application where I need to run and open JavaFX Scene/stage. I have to run it without extends Application. I've tried most of the solutions posted on Stackoverflow, none of them are working in my situation.

Here is my latest try and I am getting NullPointerException. My stage is getting NULL. This line -> [stage.setScene(new Scene(root, SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT));]

How to resolve this issue at this point? Or is there any elegant way to resolve this issue?  Here is the block of code:

```
case ADMIN:
      new JFXPanel();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdminView.fxml"));
                        Parent root = loader.load();
                        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT));
                        // Give the controller access to the main app
                        AdminController controller = loader.getController();
                        controller.setMainApp();
                        stage.show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

break;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, I would **strongly** recommend against mixing window types from different toolkits. I.e. don't use a `Stage` in a Swing application, use a `JFrame` and put a `JFXPanel` in it. Second, in the code you posted, why would you not get a null pointer exception? Where do you think `stage` is initialized?

Comment: Have you tried the approach outlined by [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm)?

Comment: *"I have to run it without extends Application."* .. why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `Stage` in a Swing application; instead, use a `JFrame` and embed the JavaFX content inside it using a [`JFXPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html):

```
case ADMIN:

    // I'm assuming this code is on the AWT Event Dispatch thread

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdminView.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(root, SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT));
            // Give the controller access to the main app
            AdminController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                window.add(jfxPanel);
                window.pack();
                window.setVisible(true);
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

break;
```

Comment: It works!  Nothing to change this is what I excepted.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably stage is null at that point. Where is the initialization of stage?

If stage is null, stage.setScene(...) will throw a nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution I've found from [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) suggested by @d.j.brown. Tested. It's working. Thought, if any one need it.

But I am now running in some other problems in my Application. Since I've used Stage.

Here in this solution I've used JFrame. If any one knows how to use Stage in Swing application, please let me know. Thanks.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
                    frame.add(fxPanel);
                    frame.setSize(FRAMEWIDTH, FRAMEHEIGHT);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setResizable(false);


                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdminViewSwing.fxml"));
                            try {
                                Parent root = loader.load();
                                Scene scene = new Scene(root, FRAMEWIDTH, FRAMEHEIGHT);
                                fxPanel.setScene(scene);
                                AdminController controller = loader.getController();
                                controller.setMainApp();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```